# What would be the best approach to overwrite multiple SeleniumJupiter configuration parameters?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, selenium-jupiter

As part of my test base class, I have something like this:

```
seleniumJupiter.getConfig().setDefaultBrowser(BROWSER.getStringValue());
seleniumJupiter.getConfig().setScreenshotAtTheEndOfTests("whenfailure");
SeleniumJupiter.getConfig().takeScreenshotAsBase64AndPng();
```

and potentially 10-20 more config parameters. Could I somehow overwrite the whole *selenium-jupiter.properties* file and change some of the properties and other left default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain your own copy of `selenium-jupiter.properties` in your project classpath, changing the values you need, and leaving the default values for the others. Then, you have two options to configure Selenium-Jupiter to use that properties:

1. Using a JVM property: `-Dsel.jup.properties=/my-sel-jup.properties`
2. Using an environmental variable: `SEL_JUP_PROPERTIES=/my-sel-jup.properties`